# Save click events for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook on a remote server (using ssh). I am using matplotlib and I want to save coordinates to annotate pictures to draw bounding boxes.
I used :

```
collector = []
def onclick(event):
    global i, collector
    collector.append((event.xdata, event.ydata))
    # Open the annotations file to continue to write
    target = open('annotation.txt', 'a')
    # Write picture and coordinates
    target.write(line)
    target.write("\n")
    i += 1
    event.canvas.figure.clear()
    event.canvas.figure.gca().imshow(images[i])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.imshow(images[0])
plt.show()
```

However, I don't why but it seems to not work anymore. Does someone know a solution to save click events on Jupyter Notebook ?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the `%matplotlib inline` backend, which does not support any kind of events (since it produces simple png images). In order to work with interactive elements and events, you would want to use the `%matplotlib notebook` backend. This means you should put the line

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

somewhere upfront your notebook.

Comment: Indeed but I don't know why I have to add `%matplotlib notebook` in the cell, it isn't working when I am using `%matplotlib notebook`at the top of my notebook

Comment: You mean each cell needs its own setting of `%matplotlib notebook`? That is quite unusual, normally it should be valid for the complete notebook if put on top of it.