# How to handle mouse events on jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with OpenCV on Jupyter notebooks. The problem is the kernel crashes when the user calls functions like `cv2.imshow()`. There are couple ways to deal with this one is redirecting the image to `matplotlibs` and another one is using `waitKey(0)` to wait input and close the windows with pressing any key.

In my case, in order to calculate homography first I have to select four points.

**Mouse Handler:**

```
def mouse_handler(event, x, y, flags, data):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN :
        cv2.circle(data['im'], (x,y),3, (0,0,255), 5, 16);
        cv2.imshow("Image", data['im']);
        if len(data['points']) < 4 :
            data['points'].append([x,y])
```

**Data collector:**

```
def get_four_points(im):
    
    # Set up data to send to mouse handler
    data = {}
    data['im'] = im.copy()
    data['points'] = []
    
    #Set the callback function for any mouse event
    cv2.imshow("Image",im)
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", mouse_handler, data)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    
    # Convert array to np.array
    points = np.vstack(data['points']).astype(float)
    
    return points
```

Eventually I'll have to click on the image. So I can't solve this problem with the methods mentioned above. How can I solve this?

Source: https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Homography/utils.py

(Note: I'm using virtual environment.)

Answer (score 0):

You should check this: [opencv.imshow will cause jupyter notebook crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236180/opencv-imshow-will-cause-jupyter-notebook-crash)

Also, you should apply `%matplotlib notebook` as stated in: [Save click events for Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242880/save-click-events-for-jupyter-notebook)